# Find if an element has a children begins with certain x JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I want to select all the child elements that has a class name begins with a certain string, or at least know if that parent has this kind of children:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myParent">
    <div class="good_child_1">
    </div>
    <div class="bad_child_1">
    </div>
    <div class="good_child_2">
    </div>
    <div class="bad_child_2">
    </div>
    <div class="very_bad_child_23452345">
    </div>
</div>
```

i want a JQuery code to select all children that start with "good_child", 
code should be something like this:

**JS:**

```
var all_good_childs = $(".myParent").find('[class^="good_child"]');
if (!all_good_childs.length)
{
    //do something  
}
```

but it didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: Does $(".myParent").find('div[class^="good_child"]') work?

Comment: what do you mean with it didn't work? `all_good_childs.length` it's 2, what result are you expecting ?

Comment: it seems to work: https://jsbin.com/faxupepiwe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: $(".myParent").children('[class^="good_child"]')

Comment: @adpro no it didn't work

Comment: Are you actually wanting if (!all_good_childs.length)?  That will enter the if only if the length is 0 or not there.  This is working as you have it on my side of things.

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcon found elements: 4 and you have only one element starts with "x-tag1"

Comment: Yours is working fine - please see https://jsfiddle.net/4g8eaw0v/3/

Comment: @ZORRO_BLANCO - I think you're expecting your if statement to be true when there are elements.  Are you?

Comment: @ZORRO_BLANCO what?

Comment: sorry, it looks like my code was working, my mistake, but thank you guys anyway

Comment: What was the issue with it @ZORRO_BLANCO?

Comment: The code worked fine i had a typo mistake...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {    
    console.log($("div[class^='good_child']"));
});
```

Comment: @ZORRO_BLANCO this will do it!

Comment: I all ready know this code, but it won't work for me, i have a certain parent that should have a certain children...in your code it will select all elements in the page that start with "good_child", but this is not my case